# How to create a static player top or bottom of wordpress?

Tags: embed

I'm creating two websites, one radio station and one bands website. I want to add a player (already have a php with the player in it) to the top of the page, like a frame.

The main point is to have the player playing music while people can navigate to other pages without interrupting the player.

I've created the following:

```
<frameset framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" rows="*,65">
    <frame name="main" target="_self" src="http://www.website.com/index.php" scrolling="auto">
    <frame name="footer" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" src="http://www.website.com/player">
    <noframes>
```

However this creates a loop.

Comment: What do you mean "a loop"? An audio loop? If so, it doesn't has to do with WordPress.

Comment: No, not an audio loop. The bottom iframe starts duplicating on top of itself.

Comment: Rather than using a frame why not give your users the ability to pop the player out in a new window. This will give your users more control if they want to listen to it through out the whole site, while browsing other sites or the ability not to. Know what I mean?

Comment: Nicole, thanks for the suggestion. That'd be plan B, I think it will better for the audio to auto-start and not have the user looking for a link to play anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Child theme for TwentyEleven:

- create the child theme folder, `twentyhalf`
- create a `style.css` file with the content:

```
/*  
Theme Name: Framed Audio
Theme URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69624
Version: 1.0
Description: Index page with framed content - one frame points to a parent page with the slug of 'sample-page' and the other for a folder at the root level named 'radio'
Template: twentyeleven
*/   
@import url("../twentyeleven/style.css");
```

- copy the parent theme `index.php` into the child theme folder
- substitute `get_header()` and `get_sidebar() + get_footer()` with the parent content of `header.php` and `footer.php`, and adapt to suit your site's framed Front Page
- set the "*Front page display*" in `Reading Settings (/wp-admin/options-reading.php)` to "*Your latest posts*".
- `/sample-page/` is the slug of a WordPress page with the "true" first WP
  page. For exhibiting a "blog" page some template/shortcode will be
  needed.
- `/radio/` is an actual folder with an `index.html` containing the audio player.

#### Sample `index.php` for the child theme

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title>HAND WRITTEN TITLE</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<frameset rows="*,65" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame name="main" src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/sample-page/" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
<frame name="footer" src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/radio/" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" noresize>
<noframes></noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

==============

**Attention to the "Home" link in the navigation menus**: this one must be directed to the frame "main", otherwise the frameset will duplicate the footer.

==============

Comment: Hmm, being playing with this for a while, can't seem to get it to work yet. Can you elaborate what main is? Is it a folder? Also, to confirm, this goes inside the THEME's index?

Comment: I've updated the Q with better naming examples, and explicit `index.php` file reference.

Comment: @AntonioCouto Ok, answer rewritten with working child theme example. Good luck!

Comment: @brasofolio, you mentioned to create an index.php in the childs theme from the parent theme, but then also to rewrite it again with the frames. Did i miss something?

Comment: Thanks for the help! However I feel your approach will prevent me from updating or changing the theme with ease. My solution was to move the wordpress install into a new folder, and created a simple index.html that calls the new folder and the 'radio' folder. Again, thanks!

Comment: The point of a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) is being able to update the parent theme with ease :) :::: Glad that you sorted that out, and it's the easiest solution for sure! :::: Please mark the Question as solved, so it don't hangs around in the "unanswered" category. :::: And feel free to add your own solution as another Answer. Cheers!